# How to join a sql table with another where each value in one that matches repeats the amount of row in the other one?

Tags: sql, join, cross-join

Table 1:

```
zipCode    Brand 
11111      Toyota
```

Table 2:

```
zipCode   Dealers
11111     SouthDealer
22222     NorthDealer
33333     EastDealer
```

If I do a left join on zipCode then I get

```
zipCode    Brand    Dealers
11111      Toyota   SouthDealer
22222      BMW      NULL
33333      Honda    NULL
```

How to fill Null values?

```
zipCode    Brand    Dealers
11111      Toyota   SouthDealer
22222      BMW      SouthDealer
33333      Honda    SouthDealer
```

What if Table 1 contained multiple rows like below and I wanted to get the same result.

Table 1:

```
zipCode    Brand   
11111      Toyota
22222      BMW      
33333      Honda
```

Expect result to be something like this:

```
zipCode    Brand    Dealers
11111      Toyota   SouthDealer
22222      BMW      SouthDealer
33333      Honda    SouthDealer
11111      Toyota   NorthDealer
22222      BMW      NorthDealer
33333      Honda    NorthDealer
11111      Toyota   EastDealer
22222      BMW      EastDealer
33333      Honda    EastDealer
```

Comment: Where does BMW and Honda come from, none are in your first two tables.

Comment: Why would you fill those nulls with `SouthDealer`? Are you **inventing** data when it's not available?

Comment: Not necessarily inventing data. It is just a way to list what brands and zip codes each dealer can potentially be.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> list what brands and zip codes each dealer can potentially be

It looks like you want all possible combinations between the two tables. If so, you can just `cross join` them, to generate their Cartesian product:

```
select t1.zipcode, t1.brand, t2.dealer
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```

You might also want to check if each combination actually exists (ie if the dealer exists at the zip code of the brand); here is one way to do it with `exists` and a `case` expression:

```
select t1.zipcode, t1.brand, t2.dealer,
    case when exists(select 1 from table2 t20 where t20.dealer = t2.dealer and t20.zipcode = t1.zipcode) 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end dealer_exists
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```